# How to custom fiori launchpad header

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a fiori project. I'd like to custom the header of fiori launchpad. These are what I want. See screenshot below.

1. Add a dynamic title to launchpad header.
2. Add an item options menu.
3. When click the item, show a select dialog contains a list.
4. When select one item of the list, change the dynamic title and refresh
   the tiles base on the selected item.

[image]

I have got some information about [Adding and Removing Custom items to the options menu](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/de/0d/ff727359ea4ccd8f1c5ff8158840dc/frameset.htm?original_fqdn=help.sap-ag.de). ***But, where to place the code?***

Comment: thank you for helping me let the screenshot show!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3706745) it says:
“You can add these lines in component.js file of your app.
You may surround them with a try-catch statement, 
to handle situation when your app runs outside of Fiori Launchpad (and rendererExt cannot be instantiated).”

[Extending Fiori Launchpad](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3728846) might also be helpful.